# Google Script to copy rows to another spread and allow for editing of copy data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a form that populates a master spreadsheet, and I have another spreadsheet that gets data from the master sheet.  Using the script below I can't edit the information that is copied because whenever the script runs it replaces the edited information to match the master sheet. How can I get the script to only copy data if data hasn't been entered.

ColumnQ's data never changes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
    var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('Lead Sheet');


    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX')
    var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('Lead Sheet');
    var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
    var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you only want to copy over new rows from the "master" sheet that aren't already in the "target" sheet? If so, assuming column Q is like your "unique key," then you'll have to pull at least this column from each sheet and compare the results. Here's some tested code that does what I believe you want:

```
function myFunction() {
  var qOffset = 16;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Target');

  var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetValues = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var deltaValues = [];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < sourceValues.length ; i++){
    var rowsMatch = false;

    for(var j = 0 ; j < targetValues.length ; j++){
      if(sourceValues[i][qOffset] == targetValues[j][qOffset]){
        rowsMatch = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(!rowsMatch){
      deltaValues.push(sourceValues[i]);
    }
  }

  if(deltaValues.length > 0){
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, deltaValues.length, deltaValues[0].length).setValues(deltaValues);
  }
}
```

Also, I just recently tackled a similar project, but instead of using a "master" sheet, I wrote a function that's triggered by form submissions. When the function is called, it searches my sole spreadsheet for the data; if it finds it, it updates the row, if not, it appends a new row. If that's of any interest to you, I can post parts of the source code.